# What's the difference between branching and committing?

Tags: git, github, netbeans, version-control

I'm beginning with the basics of GitHub, because I have to work as a programmer and others have told me about creating/cloning a directory in NetBeans and committing /branching a project; but I don't totally understand the difference between commit and branch. Like you can see here:

https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

> By default your repository has one branch named master which is considered to be the definitive branch. We use branches to experiment and make edits before committing them to master.
>
> When you create a branch off the master branch, you’re making a copy, or snapshot, of master as it was at that point in time. If someone else made changes to the master branch while you were working on your branch, you could pull in those updates.

I understand that I have a branch named `master` that is the definitive branch and other branches that I can create in NetBeans clicking in my project of NetBeans. I know how to do this in NetBeans, but I don't understand the difference between branching and committing.

I can use branch to do some experiments or changes in my code to see the results before merging my project with the master. Maybe I am working with some changes in my code, but I can't get what I want to get, this is the best moment to do some tests to see the results while doing branching.

And I'm unable to understand this:

**"If someone else made changes to the `master` branch while you were working on your branch, you could pull in those updates."**

I can't read a book about Git, because I don't have time to do it, but I have some problems with Git (GitHub).

My teacher explained me in the job that you have to do branching before committing.

Comment: There are actually some fairly deep philosophical issues with what, precisely, a branch *is*, and whether a branch can exist without commits and/or vice versa. However, since you don't have time to read a book, I won't point you at the book.

Comment: Figure out how things work in a single, local repository before you start trying to figure out how to interact with remote repositories (pulling, fetching, etc...).

Comment: Pro Git is a very good resource and available freely online. You do not need to read the entire thing. Pick and choose what is helpful at any given moment. You will find that the first 3 chapters contain 90% of what you need.

Answer (score 4):

In Git, a "branch" can be thought of as a pointer to a commit. Often, people will also use the term "branch" to refer to the set of commits comprised by the commit being pointed to and all of its ancestors (sometimes this dual-meaning leads to confusion).

A "commit" is a saved version of the code. Commits are arranged in a tree where each commit (except for the first) has one or more ancestor commits.

Strictly speaking, "branching" is simply adding a new pointer and pointing it to some commit. "Branching" does not change the tree of commits in any way (it does *not* add a commit). However, people often use this term to mean branch and commit.

"Committing" adds a node to the tree of commits. When you perform a basic commit, Git also repoints the branch you are currently using to point to the new commit.

If someone is telling you to "branch" they're telling you to

1. create a new branch that points to the commit your changes are based upon
2. checkout your new branch (this is usually done with the same command as the previous step)
3. commit your changes (while still on the new branch you just checked out)

For example, to branch off of master, do this:

```
git checkout master
```

(code... code... code...)

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git commit -am'commit message for new branch'
```

Now `new_branch` is pointing to a new commit whose ancestor is the commit that `master` is pointing to.

You also ask about this statement:

> "If someone else made changes to the master branch while you were working on your branch, you could pull in those updates."

Suppose you've just followed the example above and then you `fetch` master after someone made a single commit to the master branch. Now you'd have a fork in the branch. One tip would be `new_branch` and the other tip would be `master`. You could then `merge` the two branches (i.e. make a new commit pointed to by both branches, closing the fork). Alternatively, you could use `pull` which does the same thing, but in one step.

Comment: So if I delete a branch, that's just removing a special name, right?  It doesn't delete the changes at that branch or permanently remove any code we wrote, correct?  **__I__** wouldn't design Git that way, at least

Comment: @Nathanmajicvr.com if you delete a branch you are deleting a pointer to a commit. If no other branches point to that commit then that commit will be garbage collected. If there are other extant branches pointing to that commit, then it will remain. Compare `git branch -d` and `git branch -D`

Answer (score 2):

A commit is like a diary entry; a branch is like having a second diary.

A commit marks a point in time, a state, a record. You make lots of commits over the life of a project. A branch is like a duplicate diary where you might write your first drafts before merging them all back into your main diary (`master`).

Answer (score 1):

Well... committing means "to create a revision", normally on a branch (but that's not mandatory in Git). Branches (in Git) are just pointers to revisions.

When people talk about "branching" they mean to create branches and then merge/rebase/whatever them to mix code from different people/branches.

It's important to understand that on a [distributed version control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control) (DVCS) you are *always* working on *different* branches when people work on different repositories (even if they are working on a branch that has the same name).

Answer (score 1):

One of the ideas of Git is to have one stable version (**branch**) which, for example, you can show to your client and another one where you will experiment new features, apply tests, etc.

When you are going to implement a new feature to your application you do usually create a **new branch** for that feature/bunch of features. Then you work on it hard, making it shine. After, you **merge** it to the **master** (main) **branch** to show it to your customer.

[image]

On this picture every single red point is a **commit** (change) to the repository, which you make one by one during the process of development to update your application.

While every new line level on a picture is a **branch**, the top one is a **master** while the two lower ones has been made for a **new features**.

You make a **commits** one by one (which is also possible in a **master branch**) as far as the code gets changed. Finally after you has finished working on a new feature, you make **merge to the master branch** (which is also shown on a picture - look at the fifth point of the **master branch**).

In simple words, every single change you applied to the application is called a **commit**. If you work with a desktop UI Git-client like a [GitKraken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axosoft), Tower, GitHub DeskTop, etc. (a bigger list is in https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis), you usually make a **commit** to the local repository, and then after the **commit** to the local repository has been made, you **push** all the changes to the remote repository (there can be a bunch of local commits).

Answer (score 0):

One thing worth remembering is that **A BRANCH IS JUST A POINTER TO A COMMIT**.

It's simply a textual reference, e.g. `my-feature-branch`
to some commit, e.g. `67ge3460`.
Why do we need it, then? Well, obviously because it's easier to remember `my-feature-branch` than `67ge3460`*.

```
% cd .git/refs/heads 
user@my-mac [my-feature-branch]
% ls
my-feature-branch
user@my-mac [my-feature-branch]
% cat my-feature-branch 
**67ge34600265f01eebd0ae69b8de81a13c2479cb**
user@my-mac [my-feature-branch]
```

Git stores name and content of all branches in `.git/refs/heads` folder. A branch, as you see above, is just a file with its content being some commit. I have only one branch in my repo, and its content is a SHA1 hash `67ge346002..` which is the only commit I had made in my repository. So, `my-feature-branch` is only a pointer to my commit `67ge346002..`.

Note, the SHA-1 hash `67ge346002..` need not be a 'commit' unless we knew it was so (we know because .git/refs/heads folder stores branch info and a branch stores commit info). 'Commits' are only one of 4 types of 'objects' in git that use SHA-1 hashes as unique identifiers. We can also 'git cat-file' a SHA-1 hash to ensure it is of type ('-t') commit:

```
% git cat-file -t 67ge34
commit
```

*I believe Git strongly encourages you to use branches to move between commits and not jump between commits directly for this reason.

Answer (score -2):

I understand the following:

1. Every person is a branch. If there is three persons, there will be three branches.
2. A person creates a branch that is associated to his/her repository, and then he/she works on his/her own branch making changes to his/her code. But do you have to do a commit? My teacher explained to me that after doing some changes and working on a branch, you have to do a commit in [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) (there exist this possibility).

Comment: Every person is not a branch.  The number of branches has almost no relation to the number of people.  It's closer to true that typically, in addition to the "origin" repository, every person has a clone, and each clone can have copies of the branches in the "origin" as well as zero or more local branches.  But even that glosses over a lot.

Comment: Don't confuse the repository manager's policies with git's capabilities. The repository manager may have a policy that each team-member has one and only one branch, but, in general that's not true. Furthermore, you can create as many branches as you need on your local repository--just don't push them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813582/whats-the-difference-between-branching-and-commiting/43813949#43813949